# Javascript function should not return if the return value is null

Tags: javascript, function

I want to write a function in javascript that will not return if return value is null but waits till the return value is not null and then returns. I have the code below

```
function doNotReturnIfNull() {
var returnValue = null;
try {
    returnValue = Method.getValue();
} catch (err) {
    //Method is not yet available so it throws an error
    // wait a few seconds and try again since method will be available in the next 2 secs
    setTimeout(doNotReturnIfNull, 100); 
}
//when not null, return a value
return returnValue; }
```

How do I write this function such that it does not return until `returnValue` is not null without using a callback. The `Method` object is being loaded asynchronously.

Comment: You can't do that... you need to change the logic to use a callback method

Comment: What Arun said. Unless you can force the asynchronous method to become synchronous, `return` will not work. Otherwise, either use a callback, or a promise.

Comment: You can sort of do that in nodejs using the fibres module. The Meteor framework makes heavy use of fibres to hide async behavior behind what looks like synchronous functions. I took a quick look at fibres a while back and decided that it was way more difficult to understand what's going on if you have to debug code. How can fibres do this? It was written in C so it had low-level access to the js interpreter allowing it to re-order code. If you're writing in the browser you're out of luck. There's nothing you can do but use callbacks. I highly recommend learning to use callbacks in any case.